# ASP.NET Controls - SPGrid equivalent

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, controls

I am experimenting with some ASP.NET for our reports system.  I have played around with Sharepoint 2010 and like quite a few of the interface features.

Whilst the reports system is not particularly ugly I would like to implement some of that look and feel in the reports system.  Particularly the SharePoint SPGrid pictured here...

[image: SPGrid].

Does anyone know of any free controls that implement this functionality that are available for ASP.NET?

Cheers,

Andez

Answer (score 0):

There are some ASP.NET [RadControls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx) by Telerik that have some similar features and look/feel.

However, you'd probably be better off using a couple of JQuery plugins ([Context Menu](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/context-menu) & [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/)) that are superior in pretty much every way to the OTB SharePoint controls.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for free controls, I think that you can check [CodeProject ASP.NET - GridControls](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/#Grid+Controls).

Samples
[SDXGrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/SDXGrid.aspx)
[Grouped_Gridview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Grouped_Gridview.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ahmed will investigate

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called "context menus" in sharepoint.

There are a lot of tutorials and plugins but the keyword search if your best bet. If you want to create one from scratch you can do this easily with the following URL http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc163848%28en-us%29.aspx

Although I would use a jQuery Plugin something along the lines of - http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc163848%28en-us%29.aspx

Comment: Cheers brian - will have a look.  Not used jQuery yet.